# How to format markdown extra table?

Tags: html, markdown

I would like to format a table using using markdown extra / html. I would like every other row  to have a grey background for readability. Also I would like to be able to set the width of the table. To accomplish the second part I tried this:

```
<div style="width:300px">

header 1 | header 2 | header 3
-------- | -------- | --------
row 1    | a        | b
row 2    | c        | d       
row 3    | e        | f        

</div>
```

This did not work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you really sure that markdown is your best option? "Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is not to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a publishing format; Markdown is a writing format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text."

Comment: Thanks for the reply dbd. I'm not sure what my best option is. I know the creator of the content for my college basketball site is not going to learn html any time soon. Most of his articles contain tabular data, and asking him to write an html table for every blog post is unrealistic. He is comfortable with markdown syntax, but in some cases it doesn't look right to have a table spanning the width of the entire page.

Comment: I can see your problem, you should be able (imho) to limit the width with parent element. Se my answer for using CSS to every other row issue.

Comment: Thanks again dbd... I'm gonna test your answer and I'll report back. As for adjusting the width of the table: `<div markdown="1" style="width:300px"> seems to do the trick.

Comment: click the jsfiddle link for instant test.

Comment: Works like a charm. Nice one dbd!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the CSS3 selector for every other row

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ccc;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6GNCu/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to transform markdown text to HTML, then you will apply css style to the table.

Alert: Markdown syntax don't support tables.
You will must to use a markdown fork that supports extra formatting.

**[Look this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888985/what-markdown-c-sharp-library-should-i-use/18784521#18784521)**